# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded canvas requestAnimFrame

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently working on a javascript canvas 2D game engine and I'm having some issues regarding `requestAnimFrame`.
It seems to me that I'm doing it correctly but after some time I get the following error `(Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded)`

You can take a look of the source here: http://snipt.org/vxij1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this line:

```
requestAnimFrame(this.mainGameLoop());
```

should be this:

```
var self = this;
requestAnimFrame(function() {self.mainGameLoop()});
```

so that your callback is called later as a callback, not executed immediately.

Comment: Yeap that was it... Thank you very much ;)